# How to check the values of object created in method under test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I am testing a method of service layer which creates a new object and calls another service with that object.

There is some processing involved in the method upon which some values are set into the created object.

How to verify whether correct values are set in the object?

```
public class A{
    void method aMethod(){
        //some json parsing... a = someValue;
        Xobject xobject = new Xobject();
        xobject.setValue(a);

        someOtherService.someVoidMethod(xobject);
    }
}
```

Wanted to check the values of xobject.

Comment: what do you want to test? Do you want to test whether `setValue` sets `a` in `xobject` or other service's methods sets some values in `xobject`?

Comment: @Navjot , Wanted to test whether 'setValue' sets 'a'.

Comment: `assertEquals(a, xobject.getValue())`?

Comment: @Federico In the test method, I couldn't access xobject.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice this is not the test method.

Comment: you can use `verify` from mockito whether the `setValue` function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Mockito to setup the mock for `someOtherService` then you can use the Mockito ArgumentCaptor to capture `xobject` and in your test you can access the variable and assert on it.

https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solution presented by Jocke you could do the following: Create  a helper function that creates the `xobject` for you:

```
public class A {
    Xobject makeXobjectFromJson(){
        //some json parsing... a = someValue;
        Xobject xobject = new Xobject();
        xobject.setValue(a);
        return xobject;
    }
    void method aMethod(){
        Xobject xobject = makeXobjectFromJson();
        someOtherService.someVoidMethod(xobject);
    }
}
```

Testing the helper function allows you to test the algorithmic part of your code with unit-testing, possibly even without need to mock anything.  The interaction with `someOtherService` can then be tested in integration testing.